# I have some issues with importing node moduels

Tags: reactjs, typescript, module, material-ui

I am going to import @mui/styles in my react project.
But I got some errors like below.

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/styles
npm ERR!   @mui/styles@"*" from the root project
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

I am using React 18.1.0 and @mui 5.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use `npm i @mui/styles --force`